# Exporting multiple shapefiles (mixed geometry types) into one KML?

Tags: shapefile, kml, open-source-gis, kmz

Is there a way, using open source software, to export multiple shapefiles of mixed geometry types, and different attributes, into one KMZ/KML file?

Something similar to from ArcMap "Map to KML", but styling information is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use R with `sf` package. It has an object kind called `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, you can merge different kinds of geometries and export them to google earth.

With a basic reproducible example:

```
library(sf)

geomcoll <- c(st_linestring(matrix(1:6,3)), st_point(1:2))

plot(geomcoll)
```

[image]

```
geomcoll <- st_sfc(geomcoll,crs='+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ')

st_write(geomcoll,'test.kml')
```

[image]